# ImportError: No module named <modulename> in python 2.7

Tags: python

I am getting this error when I try to import a another python class in a different directory.

this is how my folder structure looks like:

```
main
    /prerequisites
         - __init__.py
         - BitesizeClusterInfo.py
         - ComponentStatus.py
__init__.py
BitesizeDecorator.py
BitesizeImp.py
BitesizeInterface.py
constants.py
execute.py
main.py
```

I am trying to import `BitesizeDecorator.py` from `BitesizeClusterInfo.py` and I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "ComponentStatus.py", line 1, in 
>       from BitesizeDecorator import BitesizeDecorator
>   ImportError: No module named BitesizeDecorator

And this is how my code snippet for `BitesizeClusterInfo.py` looks like:

```
import os

from BitesizeDecorator import BitesizeDecorator
from execute import Execute

class BitesizeClusterInfo(BitesizeDecorator):
    def __init__(self, bitesize):
        super(BitesizeClusterInfo, self).__init__(bitesize)

    def test(self):
        super(BitesizeClusterInfo, self).test()

        # add command below
        print("\n[1] - Checking cluster info...\n")

        # grep the output for ease of reading
        cmd = "kubectl cluster-info | grep -E 'master|DNS'"
        print(Execute.check_if_exists(cmd))
```

Can someone please help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

it will be:

```
from main.BitesizeDecorator import BitesizeDecorator
```

Comment: In vs code, it says `Unresolved import` and gives the error `No module named main.BitesizeDecorator`

Comment: is there any class or methods with name BitesizeDecorator in side BitesizeDecorator.py file

Comment: No, but it has its constructor

Comment: you are importing BitesizeDecorator in BitesizeClusterInfo class? Is BitesizeDecorator is a contructor? then import its class name

Comment: `BitesizeDecorator`  is a class with a constructor.

Comment: `from main import BitesizeDecorator`  try this? and is main a folder name?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the position of the file `BitesizeClusterInfo.py` to the main folder to make you line work.

Or use

```
from main.BitesizeDecorator import BitesizeDecorator
```

and if your main folder is the project source :

```
from main.BitesizeDecorator import BitesizeDecorator
```

Comment: In vs code, it says `Unresolved import` and gives the error `No module named main.BitesizeDecorator`

Comment: try `from .BitesizeDecorator import BitesizeDecorator`. If your main folder in vscode is the first in the path

Comment: No luck. It still the same. I don't know what is really wrong with `python`